# Way to clean autocomplete in Vim and .vimrc problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created a [thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/527/vim-code-completion-under-ros) to solve my problem regarding code completion problem in vim. I planned to clean all vim, omnicompletion, and all the dependencies. I was following a [guide](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2367-the-autocompletion-c-c-in-vim) for autocompletion purpose. How do I clean all of them? I need to do this because I want to reinstall the stuff hoping the autocompletion problem will solve.

In the process of reinstalling the autocompletion stuff which I use the previous [link](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2367-the-autocompletion-c-c-in-vim), I got confused wheather I should put the configuration in ~/.vimrc file (created by myself) or the one which is already available located in /usr/share/vim (named as vimrc).

Hope somebody can guide me on this matter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9616/way-to-clean-autocomplete-in-vim-and-.vimrc-problem/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Always edit your ~/.vimrc file.  If you mess with /usr/share/vim, you will affect other users on the system.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-04-01**:
You have to create the ~/.vimrc file and the ~/.vim directories

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-04-01**:
My version is 0.41.  All of my configurations are posted on my github account.  You can actually just check it out, if you are interested.  http://github.com/mjcarroll/dotfiles

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-31**:
Following this link "http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520", your omnicppcomplete  is 0.41, or 0.4 version?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-31**:
Upon reinstalling, I need to create our own .vim directory and .vimrc file, right? By default, for new installation, I don't see them. I just want to confirm my understanding..